# add watch on a non scope variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to add watch to a non scope variable. I want to add a watch to local variable. I have something like this

```
 function EditAssetRegistryController(assetregistryService, manufacturerService, assettypeService, projectService, $localStorage, $routeParams) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.manufacturers = [];
        vm.projects = [];
        vm.asset_types = [];
        vm.ch_group_uniq = 'none';
}
```

here is there a way to add watch to vm.ch_group_uniq?
I know how it will be done with scope variable but I have scenarios where I have to check many complex variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$watch` will not work as normal syntax with `controllerAs`. You need to bind it to `$scope`, and then you can watch that variable:

**Code**

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function (ch_group_uniq) {
  return this.ch_group_uniq;
}), function (newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log('Name changed to ' + newVal);
});
```

Here is the reference [**Todd Motto Article**](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Answer (score 23):

Well, you can easily add a watch for *anything* by passing a function as the first parameter:

```
$scope.$watch(function watchFunction(scope) {
    return vm.ch_group_uniq
}, handler)
```

A few things to consider: `watchFunction` must return *the same value* if nothing has changed. This can lead to some gotchas, for example, returning the result of some array operations: `[1,2,3].filter(...)` will always return a new array, and lead to an endless `$digest` cycle. Also note the third parameter of `$scope.$watch`, which indicates whether to use an identity comparison, or `angular.equals` when comparing the values. (Check out the docs for further information - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

However, your specific problem seems to be trying to use `controllerAs` and custom `$watch`-es. There's a very handy library that addresses this issue specifically: https://github.com/christopherthielen/angular-360-no-scope

Comment: good solution, but when the variable change it doesn't affect watch directly unless there is any other changes in the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner syntax using ES6

```
$scope.$watch(() => {
    return this.thingToWatch;
}, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    // Your code here...
});
```